# The Join chain in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this situation:

```
SELECT I.CHFID InsuranceNumber, I.OtherNames, I.LastName, I.DOB BirthDate, I.Gender, F.Poverty PoveryStatus, C.ConfirmationTypeCode ConfirmationType, F.FamilyType GroupType, F.FamilyAddress PermanentAddress, I.Marital MaritalStatus, I.CardIssued BeneficiaryCard, l.LocationCode CurrentVillageCode, I.CurrentAddress CurrentAddress, P.Profession, I.Education, I.Phone PhoneNumber, I.Email, I.TypeOfId IdentificationType, I.passport IdentificationNumber, HF.HFCode FSPCode  FROM tblFamilies F
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblInsuree I ON F.InsureeID = I.InsureeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLocations L ON L.LocationId = F.LocationId
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblConfirmationTypes C ON C.ConfirmationTypeCode =F.ConfirmationType
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFamilyTypes G ON G.FamilyTypeCode= F.FamilyType
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProfessions P ON P.ProfessionId= I.Profession
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHF HF ON HF.HfID=I.HFID
WHERE 
I.CHFID=@CHFID
```

I wrote this in LINQ:

```
var x = imisContext.TblFamilies
                        .Join(imisContext.TblInsuree,
                            f => f.InsureeId,
                            i => i.InsureeId,
                            (f, i) => new { TblFamilies = f, TblInsuree = i })
                        .Join(imisContext.TblLocations,
                            l => l.TblFamilies.LocationId,
                            i => i.LocationId,
                            (f, i) => new { TblFamilies = f, TblLocations = i })
                        .Join(imisContext.TblConfirmationTypes,
                            c => c.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.ConfirmationType,
                            i => i.ConfirmationType,
                            (c, i) => new { TblFamilies = c, TblConfirmationTypes = i })
                        .Join(imisContext.TblFamilyTypes,
                            c => c.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.FamilyType,
                            i => i.FamilyType,
                            (c, i) => new { TblFamilies = c, TblFamilyTypes = i })
                        .Join(imisContext.TblProfessions,
                            c => c.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblInsuree.Profession,
                            i => i.ProfessionId,
                            (c, i) => new { TblInsuree = c, TblProfessions = i })
                        .Join(imisContext.TblHf,
                            c => c.TblInsuree.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblInsuree.Hfid,
                            i => i.HfId,
                            (c, i) => new { TblInsuree = c, TblHf = i })
                        .Where(r => r.TblInsuree.TblInsuree.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblInsuree.Hfid == insureeNumberINT);
```

I have a problem with this:

`c => c.TblInsuree.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblFamilies.TblInsuree.Hfid`

Is this how it should be?
There are too many nestings in these tables

This is just a part of the whole

Comment: Don't use joins. Use relations and navigation properties. LINQ isn't a SQL replacement, it's a language that works on top of an ORM like EF. It works with entities, not tables. It's *EF's* job to generate the JOINs from the relations between entitites.

Comment: This means that your C# code should have an `Insuree` class with `Location`, ConfirmationType, FamilyType, Profession properties. Each of those should be a class with the appropriate attributes too. This way, all that's needed to load an Insuree instance with all related properties would be `dbContext.Insurees.First(i=>i.ID=someID)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your assumption that the OP is using EF is unwarranted in my opinion, especially as there are no tags for it. Your assertion that LINQ isn't a SQL replacement is completely contradicted by the history of LINQ.

Comment: @NetMage you're making an assumption that other ORMs work differently. They don't. LINQ is a language on top of an ORM, not the ORM itself. And no, it's not an assertion that LINQ isn't a replacement. The history of LINQ proves this, as do the dozens of similar questions that get into serious trouble for trying to use LINQ as if it were SQL. Also, how *trivial* it becomes to write such complex queries with a well designed context/model

Comment: @NetMage in fact, LINQ can't even perform basic DML scenarios like INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE. It's only a query interface over some other provider, in this case the ORM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What ORM would that be?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than collect as you join, flatten as you join:

```
var ans = imisContext.TblFamilies
                     .Join(imisContext.TblInsuree,
                         f => f.InsureeId,
                         i => i.InsureeId,
                         (f, i) => new { TblFamilies = f, TblInsuree = i })
                     .Join(imisContext.TblLocations,
                         fi => fi.TblFamilies.LocationId,
                         l => l.LocationId,
                         (fi, l) => new { fi.TblFamilies, fi.TblInsuree, TblLocations = l })
                     .Join(imisContext.TblConfirmationTypes,
                         fil => fil.TblFamilies.ConfirmationType,
                         c => c.ConfirmationType,
                         (fil, c) => new { fil.TblFamilies, fil.TblInsuree, fil.TblLocations, TblConfirmationTypes = c })
                     .Join(imisContext.TblFamilyTypes,
                         filc => filc.TblFamilies.FamilyType,
                         ft => ft.FamilyType,
                         (filc, ft) => new { filc.TblFamilies, filc.TblInsuree, filc.TblLocations, filc.TblConfirmationTypes, TblFamilyTypes = ft })
                     .Join(imisContext.TblProfessions,
                         filcft => filcft.TblInsuree.Profession,
                         p => p.ProfessionId,
                         (filcft, p) => new { filcft.TblFamilies, filcft.TblInsuree, filcft.TblLocations, filcft.TblConfirmationTypes, filcft.TblFamilyTypes, TblProfessions = p })
                     .Join(imisContext.TblHf,
                         c => c.TblInsuree.Hfid,
                         h => h.HfId,
                         (filcftp, h) => new { filcftp.TblFamilies, filcftp.TblInsuree, filcftp.TblLocations, filcftp.TblConfirmationTypes, filcftp.TblFamilyTypes,filcftp.TblProfessions, TblHf = h })
                     .Where(filcftph => filcftph.TblInsuree.Hfid == insureeNumberINT);
```

This is one case where query syntax has an advantage as it handles the flattening transparently:

```
var qans = from f in imisContext.TblFamilies
           join i in imisContext.TblInsuree on f.InsureeId equals i.InsureeId
           join l in imisContext.TblLocations on f.LocationId equals l.LocationId
           join c in imisContext.TblConfirmationTypes on f.ConfirmationType equals c.ConfirmationType
           join ft in imisContext.TblFamilyTypes on f.FamilyType equals ft.FamilyType
           join p in imisContext.TblProfessions on i.Profession equals p.ProfessionId
           join h in imisContext.TblHf on i.Hfid equals h.HfId
           where i.Hfid == insureeNumberINT
           select new { f, i, l, c, ft, p, h };
```